# How can I find a replacement aerator for this faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

We have the following faucet, which is missing an aerator. I don't see any identifying marks, nor anything to unscrew at the end of the faucet (i.e., it doesn't seem to be a standard screw-in aerator). How can I find an aerator that fits this faucet?

[image: faucet top 3/4 profile]
[image: faucet front view]
[image: business end of faucet]

Comment: Does that whole round bulb part unscrew? It kinda looks like it might. Might spray some lime away on the whole works to get a better idea how it's put together.  It looks like maybe the white part should unscrew. Like the white was the aerator but the screens have been pushed out.

Comment: Indeed, @Zach, that's the trick. If you put that in an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that whole round bulb part unscrew? It kinda looks like it might. Might spray some lime away on the whole works to get a better idea how it's put together. It looks like maybe the white part should unscrew. Like the white was the aerator but the screens have been pushed out.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, the bottom of your faucet has a screw-in aerator. Faucets typically use standard inside thread dimensions, so you should be able to use any screw-in aerator that suits your taste.

To remove the existing aerator, try applying masking tape to both jaws of your pliers to prevent damage to the aerator in case you need to use it again. Then grasp the aerator and unscrew, turning counter-clockwise. This should allow you to remove the old aerator and see the inside threads of the faucet. Simply screw in you new aerator and you're set. You might need to apply some Teflon tape on the threads of the new aerator if you see any leaks, but it's generally a good idea to use it for male-female threaded plumbing components.

Comment: That's what I thought, but there aren't any threads. The white plastic bit seems to be press-in.

Comment: What brand of faucet is it?

Comment: I don't know - no identifying marks, and it was already installed when we moved in a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

The whole round part on the end unscrews. The white bits are the remains of a flow limiter and aerator (which drop in from the top once the assembly is removed).

While I wasn't able to find just a flow limiter/aerator that fit, it was easy to find kits that contained these parts plus another round part of a different style.